# Facebook integration using TinyFBClient

Tags: java, facebook

How can I connect to a Facebook application using TinyFBClient where I can login, see online friends, and get and send notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Download the repo at https://github.com/CarmenD/tinyfbclient and follow the example at http://apps.facebook.com/tinyclientexample. It describes this exact use case.